# Python, перезапись данных для уникальных ячеек MySQL5

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных

Есть данные вида:
ID, Name

Для поля ID в mysql (через phpmyadmin) добавил параметр "уникального" значения, то есть дубликатов в этой таблице быть не может. В итоге при попытке загрузить данные повторно, выдает ошибку:

```
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1234567' for key 'ID'
```

Но цель моя была несколько иной - предотвратить при повторной загрузке данных, создание дубликатов, то-есть я думал что ID сохранится, а его значение "Название" - обновиться. На данный момент решил "очищать (TRUNCATE)" полностью таблицу - но это кажется слишком грубым решением.

Запрос на запись данных выглядит так:

```
query=("INSERT INTO tablename(ID, name) VALUES (%s, %s)")
```

Борюсь с ошибкой:

```
try:        
    cursor.execute(query, values)
except mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError:
    cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE  tablename")
    cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Вопрос: как "перезаписывать" обновленные данные, для ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте insert с обновлением данных:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(ID, name) VALUES (%s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)
```

Хотя в вашем случае можно будет воспользоваться replace, он удаляет запись перед вставкой, если она уже есть:

```
REPLACE INTO tablename(ID, name) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Comment: по поводу replace - а если записи нет - то он получается её не запишет?  Идея такая универсальную загрузку в БД иметь. Если таблица обновилась - догрузить. Если база пустая загрузить.  Можно подробнее про ON DUPLICATE может там что то неправильно написано? у меня выдает ошибку    "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement - и надо обязательно в 2 строки или можно в 1?

Comment: @Amaroc replace вставит строку если ее нет и заменит - если есть. Судя по ошибке в execute для третьей %s нет передаваемого праметра. Можно одной строкой.

Comment: по replace понятно.  вот запрос query =("INSERT INTO tablename (name, ID, plus, minus) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=%s, plus=%s, minus=%s") все равно ошибка  "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: @Amaroc А что вы передаете как параметры для execute. Судя по приведенному вами коду у вас там переменная values и она видимо массив. И в нем должно быть 7 параметров. там их действительно 7 ?

Comment: Всего 4 параметра name (vartext), ID (int), plus ( int ) , minus (int). 7-ми нету :) пардон вот  cursor.execute(query, values) - values - это массив из xls книги полученный

Comment: @Amaroc параметров должно быть столько же, сколько %s в запросе. Он сам не догадается что на место %s ставить ... видимо name, ID, plus, minus, name, plus, minus надо туда уложить

Comment: И так и так пробовал - я думаю что то в синтаксисе приложенном не хватает.  Попробую replace пока использовать - если смысл один и тот же )

Comment: @Amaroc  вы в консоли mysql попробуйте выполнить запрос и увидите что он работает. В документации еще предлагают что то такое (что бы доп. параметров не передавать): `INSERT INTO tablename (name, ID, plus, minus) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),plus=VALUES(plus), minus=VALUES(minus)`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Спасибо! Вот теперь работает аналогично replace!